# php exec not working well when call c# .exe which using fingerprint device

Tags: c#, php, xampp, exec, fingerprint

I'm currently build an fingerprint attendance application web based with PHP. Application will installed on Windows 7. Currently I'm using Xampp 1.7.7

I understand that PHP can't access fingerprint since it server based, so I build C# apps to call fingerprint device.

C# apps work well when call by `cmd` or double click it on Windows7.

Problem comes when I trigger C# apps via PHP `exec()`. in Windows 7 seems like fingerprint device not detected.. but when I test with windows XP, it can work well..

The fingerprint apps need some library, when I do several experiment, looks like PHP `exec()` can't read the library file, but I'm not really sure about this..

what should I do to fix this..?

Answer (score 0):

I know i should comment but i don't have the right still to do so..  But i may have the awnser!

I think it is because xampp is not runing by the same window account as you when you are calling your c# program in cmd.

When you are calling your c# program in the cmd it is your window account that run it so you have to right to read all file that is needed.

But php is intended to run on a server so the user that xampp is probably creating when you install it is maybe restricted.

what i whould do is try to change the user that php run on.

I had a problem like this before and that was the case.
I wanted to fetch the cpu usage with an c# program and was doing nothing.

Good luck

Comment: did you mean "run xampp control panel as a service"? so that xampp service will run under the system account..? could you please tell the step to change the user php run on..? thanks.

Comment: @user2770861 Well the Thing is I use iis as my "apache" if you want So in iis i can create/select witch user is runing the php instance.  But just like that if you open task manager, on what user does php run? 

i will search right now on google on how to change xampp user and recoment after.